# How do I fix error : "Appear a prohibit icon"?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard

Sometime my laptop appear a prohibit icon then keyboard is disable.I am using Ubuntu 18.04

[image: This is image of error]

How do I fix it?

Comment: That icon means some unsupported function has been called from the keyboard, like some key that has no function in the software has been pressed. If the keyboard is disabled after that you should check connection and consider the possibility of getting a new one.

Comment: Can you speak clearly about "How I fix it?"

Comment: I'm not sure it's fixable.